# Center popover on the previous view

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, popover

I want to implement popovers in my app. When I change the storyboard segue option "kind" too "popover" I get an option to create a popover that has an anchor point with an arrow pointing to whatever I anchor the view/popover to. I don't want this. I want a popover that is centered on the previous view so you can still see parts of the previous view.

Picture of what i mean here:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I want the popover to behave like an independent view controller with buttons/labels etc. but obviously be smaller so you can see whats behind it. I also would like to know how to get the faded/darkened effect of the previous view after the popover shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Achieve this by using popover.swift third party library available in github.There is no issue from my end

Comment: I have a code even i am Unable to find can u please provide me any of the source i will send u the code is it ok its just a one view controller.u need to add that in you project.

Comment: could you just post the code for that view controller in a new comment and ill be able to work out the rest, thanks!